# How to disable ORM and completely exclude any connections to mySQL from a Symfony app?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 2.8 application that was using mySql before. I have recently switched to MongoDB (completely - everything that was stored in mySql is now stored in mongoDB). I want to get rid **of all the code and dependencies that involve connections to mySql** (such as parameters.yml), BUT **I don't want to remove any code that is being used for ODM** and such. How to do that? When I delete

```
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
```

from composer.json, i get the following error when updating:

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                               
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                        
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Version' not found in /home/michal/projekty/squawk/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.  
  php on line 432
```

How do i clear my app from any mysql related code without doing any harm to the ODM?

Comment: Remove config related to orm in `config.yml`

Comment: I have the same issue. Interestingly, everything works fine in my dev environment, but when I try to deploy to prod, I get the same error as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine ORM is used for don't create relationship between SGBDRM and your application Symfony. I don't know your code but if you work with this principle you don't have anything dealing with directly MySQL. Whereas I don't know without viewing code what do you do for change those.

Normally, just change your parameters.yml for stop working with MySQL.